# Is it possible to launch the Python interpreter at runtime?

Tags: python

I would like to know if a Python script could launch the Python interpreter at runtime, making variables accessible from the interpreter.

Let me explain myself. Let's say I have the following script:

```
x = 20
LaunchInterpreter() #Imaginary way to launch the Interpreter
```

Now, the interpreter is launched and we can play around with variables.

```
>>> x               #x defined value by the script
20
>>> x*x
400
```

Comment: See the first answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796474/start-interactive-mode-on-a-specific-script-line

Comment: That's working exactly as I wanted, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for a dynamic interpreter you can use [`pdb`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html). It is just a debugger though so should be used only for that purpose but can be used like in the following way;

```
x = 20
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
```

Now you will have an interpreter and you can play around with the variables.

I don't know if this is suitable in your situation but it's the closest thing I can think of with the information provided.

*Edit 1:*

As stated in the comments by skishore you can also use [`code.interact(local=locals())`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/code.html#code.interact) so:

```
x = 20
import code
code.interact(local=locals())
```

Comment: I wanted to upvote but I needed certain number of reputation. Will accept the answer as soon as I can :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `-i` command line option to Python forces the launching of a command interpreter after a script completes:

```
python --help
usage: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg] ...
Options and arguments (and corresponding environment variables):
< ... >
-i     : inspect interactively after running script; forces a prompt even
         if stdin does not appear to be a terminal; also PYTHONINSPECT=x
```

so given a file test.py that contains:

```
x = 7
y = "a banana"
```

you can launch python with the `-i` option to do exactly what you'd like to do.

```
python -i test.py
>>> x
7
>>> y
'a banana'
>>>
```