# Enabling console features with code.interact

Tags: python, console

If I start a new Python interactive session from the command line, some console features such as using the arrow keys to access a previous command, etc. are present.
If instead, however, I use `code.interact()` to start an interactive session from inside a larger script, the escape sequences aren't properly handled - e.g. pressing the ⮹ key prints `^[[A` instead of displaying the previous command.  How do I enable this feature?

Comment: That should work by default with `code.interact()`. If it doesn't, you may be using two different Python installations or something.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `readline` module to get arrow keys working

```
import code
import readline
import rlcompleter
           
vars = globals()
vars.update(locals())
                                              
readline.set_completer(rlcompleter.Completer(vars).complete)
readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")
code.InteractiveConsole(vars).interact()
```

Comment: Turns out there was something messed up in my installation so the `readline` module wasn't available.  Just fixing that problem made it work, thanks for the pointer in the right direction.

Comment: @xaxxon. Sorry; it should be "locals()". It is optional and is needed if you want the local variables visible in the new interactive session you launch

Comment: I needed the `readline.set_completer(rlcompleter.Completer(vars).complete)` to get tab completion to work. Especially if I set custom contexts, then it would not recognize those with tab completion, only the builtin ones. Thank you.

Comment: But the readline wouldn't work any more if I entered an invalid command in the intractive python shell.Any idea to solve this?

Comment: Note that on mac os you may need to run `readline.parse_and_bind("bind ^I rl_complete")` instead of the same function call on "tab: complete" - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71229303/how-does-djangos-python-manage-py-shell-keep-the-command-prompt-open/71230433#71230433 which checks for use of libedit