# Tab Complete to show Available Dynamically created Object associated

Tags: python

My goal is to dynamically create many objects using setattr and then open a python prompt. Eventually I will have a `object tree` associated with `root`.

I would like to `TAB` after `root.` to see all available objects linked with root. Can anyone suggest how to do it?

```
import code

class Foo:
    def name(self):
        print("Checking my name")
root = Foo()
new_obj = Foo()
setattr(Foo,"new",new_obj)
code.interact(banner="", exitmsg="", local=dict(globals(), **locals()))
```

Example: root has dynamically created objct `new` which works as shown in cmd.

```
>>> root.new.name()
Checking my name
```

what I want to see after pressing `TAB`:

```
>>> root.
    new
```

Comment: are you asking how to get tab-completion with `code.interact`? Because the regular Python REPL in my shell does suggest `new` when you do `root.<TAB>`

Comment: Good point. Idea is some will run this as script which will populate root with a tree of objects and open prompt at the end. Is there a way code.interact can show the tab-completion of objects? Otherwise I'll first open a REPL and import it as module and run

Comment: You can always run the code with `python -i entrypoint.py`

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50917938/enabling-console-features-with-code-interact

Comment: It is working perfectly. Thanks a lot.