# How does django's `python manage.py shell` keep the command prompt open?

Tags: python, django

When you run `python manage.py shell`, (or `shell_plus` if you have the extension), the script will import some stuff for you and then open a regular python shell for you to try commands out, as opposed to running the script and immediately closing.

I know that you can use the `-i` switch when calling a script to keep the command prompt open, for example `python -i foo.py` will run the contents of `foo.py` yet keep the shell open instead of immediately closing.

I would guess that when you call django's `manage.py shell` it somehow uses the same feature to get the command prompt to stay open and not immediately close out.

How does it work? Can I add something to any script file to make it behave the same way (without using the `-i` switch) ?

Comment: You want a prompt to input some python code or just let the terminal opened?

Comment: @Corralien I want to run a script and have the script open a terminal that remains open instead of closing immediately after running the script. Normally you can do `python -i foo.py` to do this. But Django's `manage.py shell` shows it is possible without the `-i` switch.

Comment: The standard shell management command doesn't import anything from your project automatically as far as I know. That's the selling point for shell_plus. The normall shell command just starts an interactive interpreter, the flavor of which you can specify with the -i flag. Try running the normal shell command, without importing anything you don't have access to those modules like you do with shell_plus. If you look at the code for shell plus, there's logic for importing your project's modules https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/main/django_extensions/management/shells.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of 2.2.3, the `shell` management command has three programs it can start -- `ipython`, `bpython`, and `python`.  For the first two, you can start the shells using python:

```
    def ipython(self, options):
        from IPython import start_ipython
        start_ipython(argv=[])

    def bpython(self, options):
        import bpython
        bpython.embed()
```

For `python`, django sets up readline and then uses [`code.interact`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/code.html#code.interact) to start the python interpreter:

```
    def python(self, options):
        import code
        # Set up a dictionary to serve as the environment for the shell, so
        # that tab completion works on objects that are imported at runtime.
        imported_objects = {}
        try:  # Try activating rlcompleter, because it's handy.
            import readline
        except ImportError:
            pass
        else:
            # We don't have to wrap the following import in a 'try', because
            # we already know 'readline' was imported successfully.
            import rlcompleter
            readline.set_completer(rlcompleter.Completer(imported_objects).complete)
            # Enable tab completion on systems using libedit (e.g. macOS).
            # These lines are copied from Python's Lib/site.py.
            readline_doc = getattr(readline, '__doc__', '')
            if readline_doc is not None and 'libedit' in readline_doc:
                readline.parse_and_bind("bind ^I rl_complete")
            else:
                readline.parse_and_bind("tab:complete")

        # We want to honor both $PYTHONSTARTUP and .pythonrc.py, so follow system
        # conventions and get $PYTHONSTARTUP first then .pythonrc.py.
        if not options['no_startup']:
            for pythonrc in OrderedSet([os.environ.get("PYTHONSTARTUP"), os.path.expanduser('~/.pythonrc.py')]):
                if not pythonrc:
                    continue
                if not os.path.isfile(pythonrc):
                    continue
                with open(pythonrc) as handle:
                    pythonrc_code = handle.read()
                # Match the behavior of the cpython shell where an error in
                # PYTHONSTARTUP prints an exception and continues.
                try:
                    exec(compile(pythonrc_code, pythonrc, 'exec'), imported_objects)
                except Exception:
                    traceback.print_exc()

        code.interact(local=imported_objects)
```